# Example of DI Container usage in Jooma 3.x

Tags: joomla-3.x

Joomla! 3.x includes DI (Dependency Injection) container.
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.DI.Container.html.
I'm curious about it's usage in my joomla component. Did anyone try to set it up?

Also that would be nice to see some examples.

Answer (score 2):

I saw it in the code but not outside of framework (in any of the extensions). I believe it gonna be used on a bigger scale in Joomla! 4. The main benefit from that is testability but there are others too. If you are not familiar with the concept you can see the explanation and some examples here:

1. https://github.com/joomla-framework/di
2. https://github.com/joomla-framework/di/blob/master/docs/why-dependency-injection.md