# JFactory::getDbo() deprecated-- what's the replacement?

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, jfactory, joomla-4.x

I'm running Joomla 3.9.5 and I'm attempting to update my `JFactory::getDbo()` calls (which are deprecated) to the newer format using the container. However, I'm getting the following error: `Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer()`

The code looks like

```
$db = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
```

which looks the same as what's being used in the deprecated method in `\Joomla\CMS\Factory`:

```
self::$database = self::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
```

What's the right way to get a DBO in the new containerized system?

Comment: see https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/discussions/38111

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue comes solely from confusion about Joomla! versions. These facts should clear the air:

`\Joomla\CMS\Factory::getDbo()` is deprecated in 4.0 and will be removed in 5.0. It is alive and well in 3.9.

`\Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer()` doesn't exist in 3.9 as it was only added in 4.0.

The code you were looking at is from 4.0, not from 3.9.5.

In extensions compatible with 3.9 keep using `\Joomla\CMS\Factory::getDbo()`. Use `\Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer()` only in extensions compatible with 4.0 and above.

Comment: So it basically means that Factory::getDbo is becoming useless around 2024 :) what is the question in this topic?

Answer (score 9):

If you are developing your extension only for Joomla 4.0+, you can replace

```
$db = Factory::getDbo();
```

with

```
$db = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
```

Answer (score 8):

Joomla 3.9.x has a file  public_html/libraries/classmap.php that contains all the old style Class names, and the new replacements. E.g.

```
JLoader::registerAlias('JFactory', '\\Joomla\\CMS\\Factory', '5.0');
```

JFactory is indeed deprecated. You can rewrite

```
// JFactory is deprecated
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

to

```
// Put at the top of your file 
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

// Just remove the J 
$db = Factory::getDbo();
```

btw: sometimes the factory class has already been loaded and then you can just use

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
```

What IDE do you use? 
**Some  IDE software** packages can **help you finding the right classes**.

I use **PHPStorm** (commercial software) together with **CodeSniffer** and the **Joomla code standard**. PHPStorm indicates all deprecated classes. When I click on CTRL + point the mouse on JFactory, my IDE gives a pop-up "alias JFactory of abstract class Factory". When I CTRL + click on JFactory, my IDE opens the classmap file with old/new Class names. To easily replace the JFactory with the new Factory name, I click on it, press ALT + ENTER and choose "Import Class", choose Joomla\CMS\Factory, and the correct Name Spacing is placed on top of my file.

Comment: Good answer @pe7er.  You're going to fit in nicely here.  I hope you continue to post comprehensive and insightful answers. (I like my PHPStorm too)

Comment: The `5.0` is the version when this becomes deprecated, right?

Comment: @mickmackusa I believe it will be deprecated in J4 and removed in J5

Answer (score 2):

Your comment led me to doubt my belief that `getDbo()` is alive and well.  I have tested my below techniques on Joomla3.9.5 and there are no problems.

**Original answer...**

Based on this documentation:

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Factory.html#method_getDbo

> Returns the global \JDatabaseDriver object, only creating it if it doesn't already exist.

You should be able to use `getDbo`()`.

It would look something like this:

```
use \Joomla\CMS\Factory;  // at the top of your file
$db = Factory::getDbo();
```

or you can make the [static call on the fully qualified namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748271/2943403):

```
$db = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getDbo();
```

**Later answer...**

Assuming your have set the `DatabaseDriver` in your container.  Let's say something like:

```
$container = new Joomla\DI\Container;
$container->set('DatabaseDriver', Factory::getDbo());  // this is just what I used to set the driver
```

Then you merely fetch it like this:

```
$db = $container->get('DatabaseDriver');
```

I have tested `$db` to successfully allow queries on my local.

Some references:

- https://github.com/joomla-framework/di
- https://github.com/joomla-framework/di/blob/master/docs/why-dependency-injection.md
- [Example of DI Container usage in Jooma 3.x](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/19459/12352)
  https://github.com/joomla-framework/di

---

To explain why I went to `DI`, I saw the following comment block in `libraries/src/Factory.php`:

```
/**
 * Global database object
 *
 * @var    DatabaseDriver
 * @since  11.1
 * @deprecated  5.0  Use the database service in the DI container
 */
public static $database = null;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `getDbo` method is deprecated. I'm trying to get to the newer syntax using the container.

Comment: @user101289 updated.  I don't have any prior knowledge of Containers with Joomla, so I am going on this journey with you.  Let me know if this doesn't solve where you are stuck.

Comment: @user101289 - Factory::getDbo() method is not deprecated if you `use \Joomla\CMS\Factory` class, included on the top of your file. Link: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Factory.html#method_getDbo

Comment: You reckon that is the issue in the question, Zollie?  Shall I just write `use \Joomla\CMS\Factory;` as the first line of my first snippet?

Comment: @mickmackusa - yes, you were right in the first version of your answer.