# Use Loadmodule plugin in custom component

Tags: joomla-5.x

I want to embed existing modules into the content of my custom component.  I thought I could simply use {loadmoduleid 123} within the text of my component record and on display of this record, the module would be displayed.  Alas this didn't work despite having the Content - Load Module plugin enabled.
Does this mean I have to create my own loadmodule plugin for my component?  Or is there a way to utilise the core plugin, if so how.  Any and all advice/guidance appreciated.

**Edit:**
So for some further clarification, my component has fields (title, description) in the record and I want my component to display the description which may or may not contain within the text `{loadmoduleid 123}` which is generally positioned somewhere in the HTML text.

So in my code I would generally just display the field contents:

```
<?php echo $this->item->description; ?>
```

and if the contents of the `{loadmoduleid 123}` and module_id 123 was a custom HTML module with just an image, then the output should be something like:

```
<p>Blah blah blah . . . <img src="images/testimage.jpg" alt="Test Image" /> blah blah blah.</p>
```

Comment: There are answers to similar questions at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/28650/120 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/5056/120

Comment: Thanks Neil, I'll have a read.  Cheers.

Comment: @NeilRobertson Hmmm these don't quite give me a solution where I have over 400 individual custom modules that I want embedded within the content of specific records.  I'm trying to save myself from manually importing data from these modules.  Cheers.